# Is there a way to export app store in-app payments via some API from Apple backends?

Tags: ios, api, export, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

We develop games for ios and need the most durable method to track in-app payments.

In Google Play we use google checkout API to export all transactions.

Is there a similar way to do it with IOS In-App payments?

Answer (score 1):

Upto my knowledge there is no backend server api that reveal In App Payments you should manually check them and save them in itunesconnect.apple.com